# Struggling with javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm struggling to get get javascript Promises to work.
I'm looking for a pointer or two on what I'm doing wrong.  Below is my code. I'm trying to convert `loadUserPayRateWrapped()` into a function that gets data from a database.
The behavior I'm getting, is that the whole set of wrapper code is still returning before `$.getJSON()` has had a chance to get it's data.

The function that is waiting for the data request:

```
function loadUserPayRateWrapped( projectId )
{

    var URI = "/projects/getAssignedResponsibilities?projectId=" + projectId;
    $.getJSON( URI, function ( data )
    {
        if ( data === null )
            return getDataFromCookie( "payRate" );
        else
        {
            const employeeId = getDataFromCookie( "empId" );
                    if ( data[ 0 ].alternatePay === null )
                return getDataFromCookie( "payRate" );
                    var altPayArray = JSON.parse( data[ 0 ].alternatePay );
                    $.each( altPayArray, function ( idx, element )
            {
                if ( element.uid == employeeId )
                    return element.pay;
            } );
        }

        // nothing was found, so return the regular pay rate
        return getDataFromCookie( "payRate" );

    });

}
```

The wrapper promise function:

```
function loadUserPayRatePromise( projectId )
{
    var payRateProm = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        var payRate = loadUserPayRateWrapped( projectId );
        resolve( payRate );
    });

    payRateProm.then( result => { return payRate } );
}
```

The async caller:

```
async function loadUserPayRate( projectId )
{
    try
    {
        const pay = await loadUserPayRatePromise( projectId );
        return pay;
    }
    catch(error)
    {

    }
}
```

code from the mainline that wants the data:

```
// add the default pay rate for this user
var payRate = loadUserPayRate( data.projectId );
$( "#hourlyRate" ).val( payRate.toFixed(2) );    //payRate must be populated before this line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "convert" `$.getJSON` from callback style to Promise is required and enough.

This is my example, maybe you have handle error case by yourself.

```
function loadUserPayRateWrapped(projectId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // wrap callback function into a promise
    var URI = "/projects/getAssignedResponsibilities?projectId=" + projectId;
    $.getJSON(URI, function (data) {
      const defaultPayRate = getDataFromCookie("payRate"); // extract to variable to reuse
      if (data === null) { // recommend style: if block with {}
        return resolve(defaultPayRate);
      } else {
        const employeeId = getDataFromCookie("empId");
        if (data[0].alternatePay === null) {
          return resolve(defaultPayRate);
        }
        var altPayArray = JSON.parse(data[0].alternatePay);
        var foundAltPay = altPayArray.find(p => p.uid === employeeId); // why $.each ??
        // nothing was found, so return the regular pay rate
        return resolve(foundAltPay || defaultPayRate)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Now, `loadUserPayRateWrapped` return a Promise. Then you can use Promise style to call the function, or use `async/await` style:

```
// Promise style
loadUserPayRateWrapped(data.projectId)
  .then(payRate => {
    $("#hourlyRate").val(payRate.toFixed(2));
  });

// async/await style with IIFE
(async () => {
  const payRate = await loadUserPayRateWrapped(data.projectId); // wait
  $("#hourlyRate").val(payRate.toFixed(2));
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$.fetchJSON`, which you can definitely use, I have used `window.fetch` to do this. And added `async` and `await` so that we are not using `then` block.

```js
// Added async
async function loadUserPayRateWrapped( projectId )
{

    var URI = "/projects/getAssignedResponsibilities?projectId=" + projectId;
    
    // Modified this line
    const data = await window.fetch(URI);

    if ( data === null )
        return getDataFromCookie( "payRate" );
    else
    {
        const employeeId = getDataFromCookie( "empId" );
        if ( data[ 0 ].alternatePay === null )
            return getDataFromCookie( "payRate" );
        var altPayArray = JSON.parse( data[ 0 ].alternatePay );
        $.each( altPayArray, function ( idx, element )
        {
            if ( element.uid == employeeId )
                return element.pay;
        } );
    }

    return getDataFromCookie( "payRate" );

}

// Added async
async function loadUserPayRatePromise( projectId )
{
    var payRateProm = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        // Added await
        var payRate = await loadUserPayRateWrapped( projectId );
        resolve( payRate );
    });

    payRateProm.then( result => { return payRate } );
}

async function loadUserPayRate( projectId )
{
    try
    {
        const pay = await loadUserPayRatePromise( projectId );
        return pay;
    }
    catch(error)
    {

    }
}
```

Also, in the following block

```js
$.each( altPayArray, function ( idx, element ) {
    if ( element.uid == employeeId )
        return element.pay;
});
```

returning `element.pay` from within a function will cause it to return the value to the inner function and not the outer function. So instead, you can do

```js
for (const element of altPayArray) {
    if ( element.uid == employeeId ) {
        return element.pay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise at the `loadUserPayRatePromise`

```
function loadUserPayRatePromise( projectId )
{
    var payRateProm = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        var payRate = loadUserPayRateWrapped( projectId );
        resolve( payRate );
    });

    return payRateProm.then( result => { return payRate } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return just a promise from your function, don't name it.

```
function loadUserPayRatePromise( projectId ) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var payRate = loadUserPayRateWrapped( projectId );
        resolve( payRate );
    });    
}
```

make them async

```
async function loadUserPayRatePromise( projectId ) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var payRate = loadUserPayRateWrapped( projectId );
        resolve( payRate );
    });    
}
```